# Look for specific ec2 instances in list of all running instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

**Background**

I am writing a small script where i am trying to get a list of all the running ec2 instances in a particular region. Out of that list i am trying to see if there are instances with specific names.

I have done the following.

**My Code**

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-east-1") 
reservations = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{ "Name": "instance-state-name", "Values": ["running"],}]).get("Reservations")   
tag_list = [] 
for reservation in reservations:
    instance = reservation["Instances"][0] 
    if "Tags" in instance:
        tag_list.extend(instance["Tags"])
 for tag in tag_list: 
     if tag["Key"] == "Name":
         if tag["Value"] == "primary_node":
             print("primary node is still running.") 
        if "asg-prod" in tag["Value"]:
            print("asg instances are still running")
```

I am wondering if there is a way to simplify and do the above in a more effective manner. For instance can i just add the tag value i am looking for in the `describe_instances(Filter=[{` part of the code?  I am open to any suggestions that help me do the above more effectively as i suspect i might not be doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying the filtering incorrectly. You need multiple filters, not one, and how you specify the individual filter name/value pairs needs to change.

Here's an example:

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")

instances = ec2_client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        { "Name": "tag:Name", "Values": ["WebServer01"] },
        { "Name": "instance-state-name", "Values": ["running"] }
    ]
)

for reservation in instances["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        print(instance['InstanceId'])
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct way i guess i should have added another filter.  For some reason this is not working , it is possible `"tag:Name"` is incorrect?

Comment: The filters are additive. All must be true. Are you sure you supplied the correct tag key and tag value? Case matters, so tag:name is not the same as tag:Name, for example.

Comment: I have a instance currently running with the name `cg-test` so i replaced `WebServer-01` with `cg-test` and nothing printed.

Comment: Re-run with just the instance-state-name filter. Do you get the list of running instance IDs? Re-run with just the tag:Name filter. Do you get the instance(s) with that Name tag?

Comment: right so when i re-run with `instance-state-name-filter` i do get the list but not when i run with `tag:Name` filter i don't get anything back.

Comment: Try filtering on another tag on that same instance. Add a new tag if needed for testing e.g. Env=Prod. Also, check your boto3 library is up to date. And double-check the tags on this instance.

Comment: awesome this works well! just curious is it possible to filter and search using regex? for instance let's say i have a value where all instance names start with `some-prefix-*`

Comment: Simple regex is [allegedly supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#Filtering_Resources_CLI). You can use wildcards with the filter values. An asterisk (*) matches zero or more characters, and a question mark (?) matches zero or one character.